# Speeding up emguCV methods

Tags: c#, opencv, gpu, emgucv

I have a question about speeding up a couple of emguCV calls. Currently I have a capture card that takes in a camera at 1920x1080@30Hz. Using directshow with a sample grabber I capture each frame and display it on a form. Now I have written an image stabilizer but the fastest I can run it is about 20Hz.

The first thing I do in my stabilizer is scale the 1920x1080 down to 640x480 beacuse it makes the feature track much faster.

Then I use goodFeaturesToTrack

```
previousFrameGray.GoodFeaturesToTrack(sampleSize, sampleQuality, minimumDistance, blockSize)[0]);
```

which takes about 12-15ms.

The next thing I do is an optical flow calculation using this

```
OpticalFlow.PyrLK(previousFrameGray, frame_gray, prev_corner.ToArray(), new Size(15, 15), 5, new MCvTermCriteria(5), out temp, out status, out err);
```

and that takes about 15-18ms.

The last time consuming method I call is the warpAffine function

```
 Image<Bgr, byte> warped_frame = frame.WarpAffine(T, interpMethod, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.WARP.CV_WARP_DEFAULT, new Bgr(BackgroundColor));
```

this takes about 10-12ms.

The rest of the calculations, image scaling and what not take a total of around 7-8ms.

So the total time for a frame calculation is about 48ms or about 21Hz.

Somehow I need to get the total time under 33ms.
So now for my questions.

**First:** If I switch to using the GPU for goodFeatures and opticalFlow will that provide the nessesary increase in speed if any?

**Second:** Are there any other methods besides using the GPU that could speed up these calculations?

Comment: How much of your CPU gets used? Maybe you can do the two first calls in parallel (if they aren't parallel internally) iow: Better CPU/more cores will speed it up ;-)

Comment: I have a i7-3960X @ 4Ghz and it is using 52%. It also looks like it is using all of my cores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally converted the functions to their GPU counterparts and got the speed increase I was looking for. I went from 48ms down to 22ms.